# How do I use filesmatch in htaccess to restrict access to one folder but allow access to a subdomain of the url?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to restrict access to a folder called admin, for subdomains www or no subdomain.  The following code in htaccess does that.

```
<FilesMatch "^(admin)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

The problem is that it also restricts access to this subdomain, which I do not want.

http://edit.example.org/admin

How do I use filesmatch in htaccess to restrict access to one folder but make an exception for a certain subdomain?

I want to restrict access to http://example.org/admin

but allow access to http://**edit**.example.org/admin

I am not the best at regular expressions :(

There is a similar question but without a good answer.

According to this regex tester, this should work but does not.

https://www.debuggex.com/r/y5RYSoP8Ug0rmxO1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do this using mod_rewrite rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# block access to /admin for domain example.com  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin(?:/|$) - [F,NC]
```

Comment: This does seem to work! Man I hate regex! thank you

Comment: Outside. I have another question for anyone.

Comment: I want to allow access for

good.example.com/admin

But disallow access for ALL other subdomains.  

The way I have my code now, is that I have to manually put in all subdomains to block.
`
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^admin(?:/|$) - [F,NC]
`

What can I add which also blocks ALL subdomains, except one?


Is this correct?
`
# allow the "good" subdomain. 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !good\.example\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^admin(?:/|$) - [F,NC]
`

Comment: Yes `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !good\.example\.com [NC]` would achieve that with same `RewriteRule` I showed above.

Comment: You seem to be an expert on regex and I am trying to talk my company into buying your book.

I have another issue that I cannot figure out.  The code I have should work but it is not.

I want to allow the admin directory to work for my local environment.

I have this but it's not working


  `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.docksal [NC]
  RewriteRule ^admin(?:/|$) - [F,NC]`

Comment: I have that one figured out.

But now there's another issue for another rule I need to add.

I need to block access to URL's that end with /node/*/edit 

All URL's except for

edit.example.com

so if it's www.example.com/node/100/edit it needs to be blocked

If it's edit.example.com/node/100/edit then it should NOT be blocked

Comment: Condition line would be: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^edit\.example\.com$ [NC]` and next line would be: `RewriteRule /node/.*/edit/?$ - [F,NC]`

Comment: I came up with this but have not tested it on our "edit" environment yet.   Do you think this will work as well?

It does seem to block access on url's WITHOUT the edit.  But not sure if it will work on url's WITH edit.

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC] `
`RewriteRule (edit$) - [F,NC] `

Comment: I have already given you a working rule for this. We should avoid extended discussion in comments section. If you get into a different problem please open a new question and I will assist you there.